# Change gridview text to hyperlink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with user contact information that I want to include links to their online social media profiles where their email is, so if my gridview had NAME, ROLE and CONTACT then the contact row would have the user's email address and then a link to their social media account.

Here is the code I have so far to accomplish this, I just am unsure of what to do to make the text a hyperlink on being databound

```
protected void Contacts_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

            if (dataItem != null && dataItem["Contact"].Text == "test@tester.com") 
            {
                dataItem["Contact"].Text = //where I stopped because I figured my text to the hyperlink would go here
            }
        }
```

And here is my aspx code for the gridview, I am using telerik but it is the same idea:

```
     <telerik:RadGrid ID="Contacts" runat="server">
            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="White" 
                headerStyle-Font-Bold="True" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AlternateContact" FilterControlAltText="Filter AlternateContact column" HeaderText="ALTERNATE" SortExpression="AlternateContact" UniqueName="AlternateContact"/>                       
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Role" FilterControlAltText="Filter Role column" HeaderText="ROLE" SortExpression="Role" UniqueName="Role"/>                       
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Contact" FilterControlAltText="Filter Contact column" HeaderText="CONTACT" SortExpression="Contact" UniqueName="Contact" />                      
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: It might helpful for us to see the .aspx markup for your GridView.

Comment: @msm8bball added the aspx code

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.  You can either change the `GridBoundColumn` to a `GridHyperLinkColumn`, or you can put HTML in the `GridBoundColumn`

Assuming that the bulk of your function is working properly, the change would be something like this:

```
protected void Contacts_OnItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        if (dataItem != null && dataItem["Contact"].Text == "test@tester.com") 
        {
            dataItem["Contact"].Text = String.Format("<a href=\"mailto:{0}\">{1}</a>", emailAddress, emailAddress);
        }
    }
```